# Is it valid to pass netty channels to a queue and use it for writes on a different thread later on?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, message-queue

I have the following setup. There is a message distributor that spreads inbound client messages across a configured number of message queues (LinkedBlockingQueues in my case), based on an unique identifier called appId (per connected client):

```
public class MessageDistributor {

    private final List<BlockingQueue<MessageWrapper>> messageQueueBuckets;

    public MessageDistributor(List<BlockingQueue<MessageWrapper>> messageQueueBuckets) {
        this.messageQueueBuckets = messageQueueBuckets;
    }

    public void handle(String appId, MessageWrapper message) {
        int index = (messageQueueBuckets.size() - 1) % hash(appId);
        try {
            messageQueueBuckets.get(index).offer(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

As I also need to answer the message later on, I wrap the message object and the netty channel inside a MessageWrapper:

```
public class MessageWrapper {

    private final Channel channel;
    private final Message message;

    public MessageWrapper(Channel channel, Message message) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Channel getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, there is a message consumer, which implements a Runnable and takes new messages from the assigned blocking queue. This guy performs some expensive/blocking operations that I want to have outside the main netty event loop and which should also not block operations for other connected clients too much, hence the usage of several queues:

```
public class MessageConsumer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<MessageWrapper> messageQueue;

    public MessageConsumer(BlockingQueue<MessageWrapper> messageQueue) {
        this.messageQueue = messageQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                MessageWrapper msgWrap = messageQueue.take();
                Channel channel = msgWrap.getChannel();
                Message msg = msgWrap.getMessage();

                doSthExepnsiveOrBlocking(channel, msg);    

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle exception
            }
        }
    }
    public void doSthExepnsiveOrBlocking(Channel channel, Message msg) {
        // some expsive/blocking operations
        channe.writeAndFlush(someResultObj);
    }
}
```

The setup of all classes looks like the following (the messageExecutor is a `DefaultEventeExecutorGroup` with a size of 8):

```
int nrOfWorkers = config.getNumberOfClientMessageQueues();
List<BlockingQueue<MessageWrapper>> messageQueueBuckets = new ArrayList<>(nrOfWorkers);

for (int i = 0; i < nrOfWorkers; i++) {
    messageQueueBuckets.add(new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
}
MessageDistributor distributor = new MessageDistributor(messageQueueBuckets);
List<MessageConsumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>(nrOfWorkers);

for (BlockingQueue<MessageWrapper> messageQueueBucket : messageQueueBuckets) {
    MessageConsumer consumer = new MessageConsumer(messageQueueBucket);
    consumers.add(consumer);
    messageExecutor.submit(consumer);
}
```

My goal with this approach is to isolate connected clients from each other (not fully, but at least a bit) and also to execute expensive operations on different threads.

Now my question is: Is it valid to wrap the netty channel object inside this `MessageWrapper` for later use and access its write method in some other thread?

**UPDATE**

Instead of building additional message distribution mechanics on top of netty, I decided to simply go with a separate EventExecutorGroup for my blocking channel handlers and see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is valid to call `Channel.*` methods from other threads. That said the methods perform best when these are called from the `EventLoop` thread itself that belongs to the `Channel`.